# How to import out-of-tree git history in-tree

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

The introduction to my question won't talk too much about `git`, but I hope this will still bring more light to my problem (which asks for a git solution in the end) than if I mask the real-life use-case from behind the scenes.

INTRODUCTION

In Linux kernel it is often the case that some supplier of a special driver decides to maintain it outside of the kernel tree (won't provide real examples). That means the driver is developed in a separate repository and it is built out-of-tree against some specific kernel sources (no problem, Kbuild system allows to do so). That means some Customer receives that driver and needs to build it out of tree as well.

Now, on a big number of such modules received from different suppliers, it really becomes a pain to keep track of them, as they must be built separately from the in-tree kernel modules and, moreover, individually. Additionally, the out-of-tree modules can't be linked into the kernel image during the build operation.

So, the Customer might decide to bring the out-of-tree stuff back into the kernel tree, just for the sake of an easier build process. Of course, the repository containing the imported modules is not exposed to the outside world and the Kbuild infrastructure meant to accommodate those modules is not targeted for mainline.

ACTUAL GIT PROBLEM

Here come the questions:

- Has anybody faced a similar problem?
- Does git allow "cherry-picking" from a totally different repository?

It is assumed that the file structure of the imported content need not be changed in the targeted repository, compared to the original one.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with it to write up a full answer, but I believe [subtree merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) solves your problem.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty It looks promising indeed! I will give it a try and come back with feedback later. This could save dozens of hours for me :)

Comment: This was the right choice to go forward. Because my specific situation didn't allow merge commits, instead of `git merge --strategy=subtree` I went for `git cherry-pick --strategy=subtree`, as described [here](https://freeswitch.org/a-git-tip-cherry-picking-patches-across-projects/). Thanks @thirtythreeforty and SO! PS: it is a pitty that `git rebase` can't work with different strategies like `merge` and `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how it would be maintained in the future. Let's assume we have original kernel tree (*torvalds*), your own stuff, and driver or module suppliers *A*, *B*, and *C*. Let's also assume that suppliers **are not familiar** with the kernel development process and their trees are just trees of sources of their modules, nothing else.

Consider just a simplest case. You have sources of something you need to apply your patches on top of. How do you do that?

1. Initial stage:

   ```
   % git clone git://git.example1.com/software.git
   % cd software
   % git checkout -b mysoftware origin/master
   ```
2. Developing your stuff:

   ```
   % vim lib/mynewlib.c
   % git add lib/mynewlib.c
   % git commit -s -m "lib/mylib: Implement feature Z"
   ```
3. Maintenance stage:

   ```
   % git checkout mysoftware
   % git remote update
   % git rebase --onto origin/master <HASH_OF_PREVIOUS_MASTER_HEAD>
   ```

**Summary**: here you will have your commits always on top of the most fresh *origin/master*.

Now, append to this some 3rd party supplier:

```
    % git remote add supplier git://git.example2.com/module.git
```

It means that Git supports heterogeneous remotes having no common history.

**Summary**: here you will have *origin* and *supplier* remotes, check with `git remote -v`

With current setup you may maintenance each of software in different branches.

And you may do some merge preparation, for example:

```
    % git checkout -b mymodule supplier/master
    % mkdir drivers/staging
    % git mv <MODULE_FILES_AND_FOLDERS> drivers/staging
    % git commit -a -s -m "module: move to proper location in main tree"
```

Alternative way is to use `git merge --strategy=subtree ...` instead of doing these commands and plain merge below.

**Summary**: here you will move the module files and folders to proper location in the main tree.

Merge to the main tree

```
    % git checkout -b mysoftware+module mysoftware
    % git merge mymodule
    % vim drivers/staging/Kconfig
    % vim drivers/staging/Makefile
    % git add drivers/staging{Kconfig,Makefile}
    % git commit -s -m "Enable mymodule compilation"
```

**Summary**: here you will get your tree(s) merged and ready to compile.

When need to update mymodule and mysoftware:

```
    % git remote update
    % git checkout mysoftware
    % git rebase --onto origin/master <HASH_OF_PREVIOUS_MASTER_HEAD>
    % git checkout mymodule
    % git rebase --onto supplier/master <HASH_OF_PREVIOUS_SUPPLIER_MASTER_HEAD>
    % git branch -D mysoftware+mymodule
    % git checkout -b mysoftware+mymodule mysoftware
    % git merge mymodule
```

Now, you can easily extend this to scheme with *A*, *B*, *C*, and *torvalds*.

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed answer. Would this solution allow checking out the imported out-of-tree module at different points from its own history (recorded outside of the kernel) after the module is merged in-tree?

Comment: Of course it would in **your** repository. You keep just several remotes in one tree. Basically your merge branch always is reconstructed whenever you update it from suppliers. If you are talking about merging to official tree (like *torvalds*), the answer of course it **would not**! I think the reason why is obvious.

Comment: Merging to official tree (e.g. torvalds) is out-of-question (this is clearly stated in my first post). The assumption of your answer, which you should put a stress on, is that *ALL* the relative paths in the out-of-tree 3rd party supplier repository are kept intact upon importing the data in-tree. That's also the assumption of such commands as `git merge/cherry-pick --strategy=subtree`, which I believe are good replacements for `git mv` used in your answer. What can be done if the relative paths of imported repository in-tree can't be kept the same with the original out-of-tree repository?

Comment: Another thing which I now feel like somebody should have sensed from my first post is that git accepts *heterogeneous* remotes, having no common history. This is something I would put a stress on if answering my own question.

Comment: In the end I used `git rev-list --reverse supplier/firstcommit..supplier/lastcommit | xargs git cherry-pick --strategy=subtree -Xsubtree=path/to/imported/driver/in/tree`, as described [here](https://freeswitch.org/a-git-tip-cherry-picking-patches-across-projects/). Thanks once again for your contribution.

Comment: `git cherry-pick [options] commit1^...commitN` will replace `git rev-list` + `xargs` AFAIU (note three dots instead of two).

Comment: I amended answer a bit based on your comments.

Comment: If you want to see the answer accepted, I will express some more of my concerns. 1) My question didn't touch the dynamics of `software.git`, so I consider "Developing" and "Maintenance" parts unnecessary. 2) `git remote update` fetches all my N remotes. 3) I would avoid `git rebase --onto` in such a simple context, as this smells like a propaganda of some of your git best practices, which put additional burden in understanding the answer. 4) `git merge -s subtree` is an alternative of `git mv` + `git merge` - not clearly stated. 5) Can't see any mention of `git cherry-pick -s subtree`.

Comment: 1) Doesn't make it less valuable. 2)  So what? 3) It's how Linux kernel work flow is going on. You have to re-base your changes until they made upstream. 4) I would try to amend more. 5) I don't know your particular problems, amend your question. Even after doing that my answer keeps generic way of solving such issues. P.S. I like that 2 people found the answer useful, so, feel free **not to** mark it as a right one.

Answer (score -1):

to get files from some other repository into current repos, you could use

1) git fetch to get the files from the desired branch in the other repository

2) git show or git checkout to pull the files from the branch to the working tree

3) git clear (!) to remove them later (along with all other untracked files!)

Comment: Thanks for your point of view. Unfortunately, even if I am able to temporarily bring the files from one repository to another one (given the two are not a clone of each other), it still doesn't solve my problem of actually embedding the history of one repository inside the second repository.